# Thrift / Google Protocol Buffers on Windows

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers, thrift

Looking at Thrift and Google Protocol Buffers to implement some quick RPC code. Thrift would be perfect if the generated C++ code compiled on windows (which is what I need). And of course, GPB creates RPC stubs, but no implementation.

Is there a way to get Thrift Windows friendly? Or, even better, are there any RPC implementations available freely for generated C++ protobuf stubs (a Java counterpart would be nice too, but is not necessary).

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at apache avro (http://hadoop.apache.org/avro/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Zeroc ICE](http://zeroc.com/ice.html)

Comment: Zeroc is not free for commercial use

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get Thrift Windows friendly?

According to [this page on the Thrift wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftInstallationWin32), it is not possible.

> The following instructions are for making the thrift compiler only. The Thrift C++ runtime library does not currently work on Windows. This means that you'll be able to compile ThriftIDL files to C++/Java/Python/etc., but you won't be able to compile and run the generated C++ code under Windows.

Comment: Not true. There are some work arounds for compiling to run in windows through cygwin. Search for compiling thrift c++ in cygwin. You should mostly be able to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can installing thrift following [this "guide"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368121/building-thrift-service-on-windows-7/8368431#8368431).
Look also at my solution at the bottom, to let it works on windows.