# Building thrift service on Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, thrift

What have I done?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

1) I downloaded libevent-2.0.16-stable ( [download](https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.16-stable.tar.gz) ) and I have put it to D:\sources

2) I have downloaded boostPro 1.47 ( from http://www.boostpro.com/download/ ) and I have installed it into D:\programs, selecting BoostPro Computing as mirror,  checking Visual C++ 10.0 as Compiler, and as variants:

- Multithreaded
- Multithreaded debug
- Multithreaded, static runtime
- Multithreaded debug, static runtime

3) Then I have downloaded with SubVersion, thrift sources from [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/) to D:\sources\thrift

4) Ok, now I went to D:\sources\thrift\lib\cpp and I opened libthrift.vcxproj with MSVC++ 10, included boost sources and libs ( D:\programs\boost\boost_1_47\ and D:\programs\boost\boost_1_47\lib\ ) and I have compiled it successfully.

5) I compiled .thrift tutorial's files ( thrift\tutorial\shared.thrift and thrift\tutorial\tutorial.thrift ) with [his compiler](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.8.0/thrift-0.8.0.exe)

6) I have made a new project into MSVC++ 10, linked boost and thrift libs & sources, before generated, I have moved gen-cpp dir ( generated with Thrift Compiler before, and deleting *.skeleton.cpp files ) into the project, and [this](http://pastebin.com/7qDm04yt) as main.cpp and compiled it successfully.

If you haven't found any boost lib, you can download them from [here](http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost-binaries/1.47.0/).

NOW, what's wrong?
it seems all just perfect, but, when I start my application...
[image: Screenshot]
PS: second line means "WSAStartup was not performed or WSAStartup's error".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1433) Thrift works completely on windows!

Answer (score 6):

Try inserting the following to the beginning of `_tmain()`:

```
WSADATA wsa_data;
int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa_data);

if (0 != result)
{
    // Handle winsock load failure.
}
else
{
    // rest of `_tmain()` as you have it.
}
```

Comment: better, but not resolved: http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/1171/error2mq.jpg
However, the program is runned as administrator